# If Statements using Decimal Data Type

Tags: vb.net

I have an If statement in which I need to check if a decimal number is less than or equal to 4. I planned to do so using this code, which I will paste for some clarity:

```
Dim handicap As New List(Of Decimal)
For i = 0 To handicap.Count - 1  
    If handicap.Item(i) <= 4 Then
          ....
    End If
Next i
```

However, I cannot compare the decimal to the integer type. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Both answers worked. Thank you.

Comment: If Zay Lau's answer is correct and helped you, the proper way to show that is to accept the answer (by clicking the checkmark next to it) and upvote it (by click the up arrow next to it) .

Comment: I wasn't allowed to do that for a couple of minutes, but I have done that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `If handicap.Item(i) <= Convert.ToDecimal(4) Then`

or `If handicap.Item(i) <= 4D Then`

Read more on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx